# 3D plotting lorentz python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm pretty new to python, but I've been working on this program to graph the solutions to the Lorenz differential equation in 3D, but
I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lorenz_attractor3D.py", line 3, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
ImportError: No module named mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d]
```

Not clear why. I don't know if it's because I don't have matlib installed correctly.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

def lorenz(x, y, z, s=10, r=28, b=2.667):
    """
    Given:
       x, y, z: a point of interest in three dimensional space
       s, r, b: parameters defining the lorenz attractor
    Returns:
       x_dot, y_dot, z_dot: values of the lorenz attractor's 
           derivatives at the point x, y, z
    """
    x_dot = s*(y - x)
    y_dot = r*x - y - x*z
    z_dot = x*y - b*z
    return x_dot, y_dot, z_dot


dt = 0.01
num_steps = 10000

# Need one more for the initial values
xs = np.empty(num_steps + 1)
ys = np.empty(num_steps + 1)
zs = np.empty(num_steps + 1)

# Set initial values
xs[0], ys[0], zs[0] = (0., 1., 1.05)

# Step through "time", calculating the partial derivatives at the current point
# and using them to estimate the next point
for i in range(num_steps):
    x_dot, y_dot, z_dot = lorenz(xs[i], ys[i], zs[i])
    xs[i + 1] = xs[i] + (x_dot * dt)
    ys[i + 1] = ys[i] + (y_dot * dt)
    zs[i + 1] = zs[i] + (z_dot * dt)


# Plot
fig = plt/figure()
ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(xs, ys, zs, lw=0.5)
ax.set_xlabel("X Axis")
ax.set_ylabel("Y Axis")
ax.set_zlabel("Z Axis")
ax.set_title("Lorenz Attractor")
plt.plot(xs,ys)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: You have to install the missing library

Comment: Yeah, I was able to solve it this morning. I had to install the Anaconda package and use it to install a newer version of matlib. That seemed to work, but I don't understand why.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/installing.html

Comment: conda install matplotlib